# How to prevent running ./bin/kafka-topics.sh from opening Visual Studio Code?

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code, apache-kafka

I'm trying to create a Kafka topic in Windows by executing this command:

```
./bin/kafka-topics.sh --create --topic quickstart-events --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

Upon execution, Visual Studio Code opens and presents the contents of kafka-topics.sh without creating a topic.

The only things that appear in my PowerShell Terminal is

```
 update#setState idle
```

and

```
update#setState checking for updates
```

Does anyone have ideas on how to address this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't use shell files

You need to use the included windows\kafka-topics.bat script

Or you need to run the shell script (and Kafka) in WSL2, Docker, or a Linux VM, etc